# Is it possible to steal a non secure Cookie when the Web Server (IIS) only allows Https?

Tags: tls, webserver, cookies

Is it possible to steal a non secure Cookie (Secure Flag is false) when the Web Server (IIS) only allows Https?

Comment: can't comment, sry: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fRk-wL0AQ0 please post this as comment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it is possible...

Think about it this way:

- The `secure` flag ensures that the cookie is locked to HTTPS.
- HTTPS ensures that the connection with the server (requests + responses) is tied to the server's certificate.
- The server's certificate ensures the actual identity of the web server.

Now, if you remove that first step, the cookie obviously can be sent in an HTTP request...
Which can be sent to a different server....
Which is impersonating your web server.

There are many forms of attack (e.g. DNS spoofing) that would cause you to connect with the wrong server, and of course HTTPS (using TLS/SSL) mitigates that quite well.
Even if your actual application IS using HTTPS, there is no guarantee that the bogus server is, right?

---

But let's not stop there, there is an even more trivial scenario.

You say that your web server only allows HTTPS.
That is, it will only accept requests that are HTTPS, and it will reject outright any HTTP requests.
*But that HTTP request was already sent in the clear.*

If an attacker - or [even just a careless programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) - can cause just a single request to be sent from the user's browser over HTTP, then that cookie WILL be sent. Over HTTP. In the clear. With no encryption. (I have actually seen this quite a bit in the wild, the 2nd type more than the 1st...)

Often, that is all that is needed.

Do yourself (and your users) a favor, always enforce HTTPS at *all* levels.

Comment: plus man in the middle can always be used... especially with weak https encryption

Comment: @cengizUzun sure, that's a subset of the bogus server. HTTPS should prevent that, lacking HTTPS effectively allows it.

Comment: that's why i mentioned weak encrytions... Is it easy? no. Is it possible? Yes. 

I sometimes still see 56k enc. allowed...

Comment: It depends what you mean by *rejects HTTP*. If the site listens on port 80, but the listener bounces you up to HTTPS or denies you access, then yes, the cookie was sent in the clear. But if nothing was listening on port 80 (and nobody was actively impersonating you or someone is forcing you to choose a different port like in Thomas' example below), then the TCP connection will never be established, and the unsecured cookie will *not* be sent in the clear.

Comment: @Matt that is correct, I did not get into the low-level TCP details, but what you say is (usually) correct. I say usually, because there are some real world cases that confuse matter - for example, a reverse proxy that IS listening on 80, even though the webserver is NOT. And that is besides all the many webservers and configurations that block HTTP at the webserver level, after receiving the incoming connection, or as you say, redirect the user to HTTPS.

Answer (score 6):

The core point is that **though the server only accepts HTTPS, the client *does not know it***. The human user might, but not the software client.

Suppose the following setup:

- The HTTPS-only server is `https://www.bank.com/`.
- You are the victim.
- The attacker can eavesdrop (passively) on your traffic.
- The attacker knows a Web forum that you occasionally read.

Then the attacker just has to include in the Web forum the following HTML excerpt:

```
<img src="http://www.bank.com:443/foo.png" />
```

Just that. When your browser sees that, it will open a TCP connection to `www.bank.com` on port 443; that connection will work, because `www.bank.com` actually expects incoming connections on port 443. Of course, the bank will then want to "talk SSL", but at the TCP level, the connection succeeds (SYN, ACK+SYN, ACK).

Then your browser sends an HTTP GET request over the connection. That request *will include the cookie*, in plain view, since the target is `www.bank.com` and the cookie was not marked as "secure". Of course, the server will reject the attempt because it expects a SSL `ClientHello` message, not HTTP; however, that's too late, the cookie has already traveled before the prying eyes of the attacker.

(Variants of the attacks include a more active attacker with, e.g., DNS spoofing to impersonate a fake `www.bank.com`, but the same principle remains: since the browser does not know that the server will do only HTTPS, it will gleefully send the cookie over plain HTTP.)